# Better Query for "Select" inside "Select"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any better and shorter way to produce SQL query like below?
better could be shorter query or/and **fastest performance impacted** to server

```
select TowerID, COUNT(TowerID) as 'QTY'
from (
    select TowerID, [USER] as 'QTY'
    from ColoEngDBLocal..Carriers
    where [Status] not like '%removed%'
    group by TowerID, [USER]
) as a
group by TowerID
order by TowerID
```

It seem no difference when I use this query on the small data, but when I use this on large data, the query becames slow. (I have more than 600k row)

Currently I have table as shown below

[image]

Note: I'm using `SQL Server 2008 R2`

Comment: Can you show some sample data (using DDL+DML statements i.e. create a table variable and populate it) and expected results.

Comment: And if you want a query which *performs better* then best to say that in your title/question. "Better" could mean a lot of different things.

Comment: Also for performance questions showing a query plan is always helpful.

Comment: Also if you weren't aware. but SQL Server 2008 is past its end of life and is no longer supported. You would be wise to upgrade asap.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for very fast response, i just adding some detail about data source and expecting result

Comment: @Ardi, Try my answer. Hope that helps you.

Comment: @Squirrel it was group by user, basicly i want to get rid column some_data

Comment: The condition `where status like '%removed%'` raises a performance red flag.  The SQL engine needs to search for the substring 'removed' for each value of 'status', and cannot take advantage of any indexes on the column.  You may want to see if temporarily removing this condition improves performance; if so, you may want to normalize this field or create a dedicated column to indicate that the record is removed.  If that is not sufficient, indexing the new or normalized column may improve query performance further.

Comment: Or if you can ensure that "removed" is always first, then you can change it to `where status like 'removed%' ` which can perform OK.

Comment: @drf yes, the where statement cause performance too. Currently i just create 2nd table for classify status (not using like clause), is it ok for improving performance ?

Comment: @DaleK status could be in the middle of column, thats why i need 2 %%
but, currently i just create new table to classify the status. it use exact value for status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Simple **COUNT(DISTINCT ....)** will help you.

```
select TowerID, COUNT(DISTINCT [USER]) as 'QTY'
from ColoEngDBLocal..Carriers
where [Status] not like '%removed%'
group by TowerID
ORDER BY TowerId
```

Comment: Great! this is what im looking for, never though distinct may put inside count.
thanks for the answer